# Unable to activate windows 10

Tags: windows-10, setup

Sir, i want to install windows 10.I was using windows 7 that was genuine.Then I installed windows 10 2015 version.my windows didn't active.What should I do now?if I download the windows 10 iso file from Microsoft and install that.will my windows activate???

I need to know the full process.my windows was pre-installed.now I have the key

Comment: Please use the EDIT button to add what you have tried, what errors you're receiving, and any other information necessary to answer this question. Microsoft usually tells you why you cannot activate their product.

Comment: Thank you for replying,the problem is that was  pirated.so what should I do now?

Comment: Your post says that your Windows 7 was "genuine", now you say that it was pirated. What happened in-between?

Comment: I mean the windows 10 version

Comment: You have to purchase Windows 10 in order for it to activate. Just because you has Windows 7 doesn't automatically mean you have the right to upgrade. The free upgrade period was four years ago and should have ended by now.

Comment: Yes, Win7 free upgrade to Win10 activity has been stopped. If you want to install Windows 10. I suggest that you buy an activation key for Win10. Then you could use the Windows 10 ISO file to install.

Comment: Roll back to windows 7(if you can)...or if you have the key then install windows 7 again > Download the official windows 10 iso from microsoft > run the setup and upgrade windows 7 to 10(Not a Clean install)...your windows 10 should get activated with a digital licence

Comment: also if you have the key for "genuine"  windows 7, then first try activating windows 10 using that key

Comment: How can I go back to windows 7 i have the key but its missing two digit

Comment: If I install windows 7 again with any windows 7 os.will I found the full product key?

Comment: 2 digits missing....you would have to try 1296 times to get the key :D ...anyways try to roll back to windows 7 because installing again with any windows 7 wont get the product key...BUT did you clean install windows 10 2015 version or did you upgrade windows 7 to win 10 ??????

Comment: Clean install,how can I roll back

Comment: you can not roll back if you did a clean install ...you will need to install windows 7 again with the genuine key and then upgrade it to windows 10....and for that you need the windows 7 key...but you have 2 digits missing...so you can now either buy a windows 10 key....or download a new pirated copy or try to google any windows 10 keys and try them to activate.

Comment: Hey I have the key now tell how can i go back to windows 7 and update it properly

Comment: Thanks all.now I'm using my coem windows 7